# Sort Excel file by column name containing string and integer

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort this Excel file using the second column that is Target. The Target column has data in the form of string and integer

[image]

When I do a sort on the Excel file using the `pandas.dataFrame.sort_values()` function, I get something like this:

[image]

This sorted order is wrong because Slide2.JPG, Slide3.JPG should be above Slide10.JPG etc.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [human sorting](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/). You can handle this type of problem using regular expressions in Python.

As explained in the attached article:

```
import re
def sort_nicely( l ):
    """ Sort the given list in the way that humans expect.
    """
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
    l.sort( key=alphanum_key )

data=["Slide2.JPG","Slide21.JPG","Slide10.JPG","Slide3.JPG"]
sort_nicely(data)
print data
```

returns:

```
['Slide2.JPG', 'Slide3.JPG', 'Slide10.JPG', 'Slide21.JPG']
```

Comment: how to sort the excel by column where the column values are combnation of both string and numbers?